# Under what conditions will $x^2+bx+c=0$ have both roots real and positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics, real-numbers

Obviously, $x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt {b^2-4c}}{2}$ and for real roots we must have $b^2-4c\geq 0$. But for what values of $a,b,c$ will the quadratic have both roots positive?

Comment: I think a sufficient condition should be: $\frac{-b}{2a}>0$ and $\frac{c}{a}>0$.

Comment: Well, obviously b must be negative.  And $|b| > \sqrt{b^2 - 4c}$ ... So...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in that you need $b^2-4c\geq0$. The formula also shows that $x>0$ if and only if
$$-b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}>0,$$
or equivalently $-b>\sqrt{b^2-4c}$. In particular $b$ must be negative. Squaring both sides shows that
$$b^2>b^2-4c,$$
which means $c$ must be positive. Together with $b^2-4c\geq0$ this also gives
$$b\leq-2\sqrt{c}.$$
So in summary, both roots are real positive numbers if and only if 
$$c>0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad b\leq-2\sqrt{c}.$$

Comment: Yes but what should be the precise value of $b$ in terms of $c$?

Comment: I can see why $b$ needs to be negative from the equation, but how do you derive that $c$ has to be positive from this? Don't you need $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=...+r_1 r_2$ where the roots are positive?

Comment: c can by *any* positive.  and b can be any negative.  They don't have to be related in any sense other than that.

Comment: @Ovi Squaring the last inequality shows that $b^2>b^2-4c$, hence $c$ must be positive.

Comment: @fleablood Well not quite *any*, you still need $b^2 > 4c$

Comment: You have |b| > \sqrt{b^2 - 4c} which is true if and only if c > 0.

Comment: Well my answer booklet shows that $b\leq -2\sqrt {c}$.

Comment: @fleablood I mean that you need $b^2>4c$ because otherwise you get a negative under the radical, and the OP asked for real solutions

Comment: Of course, my reasoning was continuing what you had already found. You also need $b^2-4c>0$, or equivalently $b<-2\sqrt{c}$. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: @StubbornAtom You can get that by taking the square root of both sides in $b^2 \ge 4c$, don't have time to explain the sign flip and root sign sorry

Comment: Oh, right.  Well, then solve that.  Surely that's easy.  Why'd you ask the question if you knew the answer.  Conditions: 1) b is negative 2) c is positive and 3)$ |b| > 2\sqrt{c}$

Comment: @fleablood 'Obviously' I was confused. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 4):

- Real roots: $b^2\ge4c$.
- If real roots, same sign: $\;x_1x_2=c>0$.
- If real with same sign, positive: $\;x_1+x_2=-b>0$.

Summing it up, the conditions are
$$ b<0,\enspace c>0,\enspace b^2\ge 4c.$$

The solutions can be visualised in a $(b,c)$-plane:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For $x^2+bx+c=0$, we have: $b=-(x_1+x_2)$ and $c=x_1x_2$, where $x_1,x_2$ are the roots.

Answer (score 0):

$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4c}}{2}$

1)To have any real roots at all $b^2 - 4c \ge 0$.  So $b^2 \ge 4c$.  So either a) $c < 0$ and $b^2 \ge 0 > 4c$ or b) $c \ge 0$ and $|b| \ge 2\sqrt{c}$.

2) $- b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4c} > 0$ so $b < - \sqrt{b^2 - 4c} \le 0$ so $b < 0$.

3) $-b > \sqrt{b^2 - 4c} \ge 0$ so $b^2 > b^2 -4c$ so $c > 0$

Putting all together we get $b \le -2\sqrt{c}; c > 0$.